# Purge command not repeating bulk delete

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've got a purge command on my Discord.js v12.2.0 bot and it doesn't work as I would've hoped. I wanted to be able to purge up to 1,000 messages by repeating bulk delete, but unfortunately it doesn't actually repeat bulk delete and it only bulk deletes once. Any help would be super appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'purge',
    description: "Purge messages.",
    usage: '[amount]',
    aliases: ['prune'],
    execute(client, Discord, message, args, prefix, wrongchannelpublic, wrongchannelstaff, talkingserverbump, disabledcommand, nopermission, noarguments, colour, footer1, footer2) {
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === '703316042965057546')) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(nopermission).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        if (!args[0] || isNaN(args[0])) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(noarguments).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        if (args[0] < 1 || args[0] > 1000) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(`Please provide a number between 1 and 100, ${message.author}!`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        message.delete({ timeout: 100 })
        .then(() => {
            let remainder = args[0] % 100;
            let numOfTimes = (args[0]-remainder)/100;
            try {
                for (let i = 0; i < numOfTimes; i++) {
                    message.channel.bulkDelete(100);
                }
                if (remainder > 0) { message.channel.bulkDelete(remainder); }
            } catch (err) {
                const purgeerror = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                  .setDescription(`**Execution error**\nThe \`purge\` command ran by ${message.author} in ${message.channel} failed to execute.\nError: \`${err}\``)
                  .setColor('#ff0000')
                  .setTimestamp();
                message.channel.send(`<:cross:740242485728772137> Error: \`${err}\``);
                client.channels.cache.get('740251593382821920').send(purgeerror);
                console.log(`The purge command ran by ${message.author.tag} in #${message.channel.name} failed to execute. Error: ${err}`);
            }
        if (args[0] === "1") {
            setTimeout(()=>{ message.channel.send(`<:tick:740242485908996128> Purged ${args[0]} message.`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 4000})) }, 1000)
        } else {
            setTimeout(()=>{ message.channel.send(`<:tick:740242485908996128> Purged ${args[0]} messages.`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 4000})) }, 1000)
        }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `await` so it will wait one or two seconds between each `bulkDelete` (at this time, all the `bulkDelete` are sent but they delete the same messages):

```js
const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

module.exports = {
    name: 'purge',
    description: "Purge messages.",
    usage: '[amount]',
    aliases: ['prune'],
    execute(client, Discord, message, args, prefix, wrongchannelpublic, wrongchannelstaff, talkingserverbump, disabledcommand, nopermission, noarguments, colour, footer1, footer2) {
        if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === '703316042965057546')) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(nopermission).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        if (!args[0] || isNaN(args[0])) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(noarguments).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        if (args[0] < 1 || args[0] > 1000) { return message.delete({ timeout: 100 }), message.channel.send(`Please provide a number between 1 and 100, ${message.author}!`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 7000})) }
        message.delete({ timeout: 100 })
        .then(async () => {
            let remainder = args[0] % 100;
            let numOfTimes = (args[0]-remainder)/100;
            try {
                for (let i = 0; i < numOfTimes; i++) {
                    await message.channel.bulkDelete(100);
                    await delay(1000); // wait one second
                }
                if (remainder > 0) { message.channel.bulkDelete(remainder); }
            } catch (err) {
                const purgeerror = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                  .setDescription(`**Execution error**\nThe \`purge\` command ran by ${message.author} in ${message.channel} failed to execute.\nError: \`${err}\``)
                  .setColor('#ff0000')
                  .setTimestamp();
                message.channel.send(`<:cross:740242485728772137> Error: \`${err}\``);
                client.channels.cache.get('740251593382821920').send(purgeerror);
                console.log(`The purge command ran by ${message.author.tag} in #${message.channel.name} failed to execute. Error: ${err}`);
            }
        if (args[0] === "1") {
            setTimeout(()=>{ message.channel.send(`<:tick:740242485908996128> Purged ${args[0]} message.`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 4000})) }, 1000)
        } else {
            setTimeout(()=>{ message.channel.send(`<:tick:740242485908996128> Purged ${args[0]} messages.`).then(sentMessage => sentMessage.delete({ timeout: 4000})) }, 1000)
        }
        })
    }
}
```